# Display MySQL Query in ASP Chart using multiple series

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, series

I have this table.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7xf6ibn5mr9f9yf/test4.PNG?dl=0

Basically, I want to display "AttendDet_Type" which is P, A and MC as the x-axis using multiple series (which will look like this - https://www.dropbox.com/s/v15pp818tmgf8co/test5.PNG?dl=0) and COUNT(AttendDet_Type) as the y-axis.

I managed to display AttendDet_Type for P using asp chart but I totally have no idea how to code multiple series to display A and MC. Can anyone help me out?

My ASP Code

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" SqlDataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="800" Height="500">
            <Titles>
                <asp:Title Text = "Attendance Report"></asp:Title>
            </Titles>
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1">
                </asp:Series>
                <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" Name="Series2">
                </asp:Series>
                <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" Name="Series3">
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" >
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
```

My VB Code

```
Using con As New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConString").ConnectionString)
            Dim CmdString As String = "SELECT Attendance.AttendDet_Type, COUNT(Attendance.AttendDet_Type) AS TotalAttendance FROM Student, Attendance WHERE Student.Stud_ID = Attendance.Stud_ID AND Student.Stud_Class = '1A1' AND Attendance.Attend_Date = '2014-11-12' AND AttendDet_Type = 'P'"
            Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter(CmdString, con)
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            sda.Fill(ds)
            Chart1.DataSource = ds
            Chart1.Series("Series1").XValueMember = "AttendDet_Type"
            Chart1.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = "TotalAttendance"
            Chart1.DataBind()
        End Using
```

Looking forward to receiving yall replies. Thanks!!