# MySQL - Join queries from the same table

Tags: mysql, join

Desired output -
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mnrabcefvezt89/test11.png?dl=0

I'm trying to join these 4 different queries from the same table ON Attend_Date but I have no idea how to do it.
The final output would be Attend_Date, P, A, MC (total of 4 columns)

```
SELECT Attendance.Attend_Date
FROM Student, Attendance
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT Attendance.Attend_Date, COUNT(Attendance.AttendDet_Type) as P
FROM Student, Attendance 
WHERE Student.Stud_ID = Attendance.Stud_ID 
AND Student.Stud_Class = '1A1' 
AND Attendance.Attend_Date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-01'  
AND Attendance.AttendDet_Type = 'P'
GROUP BY Attendance.Attend_Date
) ON Attendance.Attend_Date
WHERE Student.Stud_ID = Attendance.Stud_ID 
AND Student.Stud_Class = '1A1' 
AND Attendance.Attend_Date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-01'  
GROUP BY Attendance.Attend_Date
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks alot!!

Comment: Why you need 4 self join? Can you describe your problem? Maybe UNION can solve your problem http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Comment: My reason why I need 4 self-join.

My other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836104/display-mysql-query-in-asp-chart-using-multiple-series

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the same table twice in the from statement and then set them as variable names and rename everything properly. For example,

```
FROM Student S1, Attendance A1
WHERE S1.Stud_ID = A1.Stud_ID
```

and the other one

```
FROM Student S2, Attendance A2
WHERE S2.Stud_ID = A2.Stud_ID
```

problem is the outer tables and inner tables on the joins have conflicts and may be causing your issue

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys. I managed to get this result (https://www.dropbox.com/s/3l4q76mlskc8ze1/test12.PNG?dl=0). How do I join another 2 more queries from the same column as shown in this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mnrabcefvezt89/test11.png?dl=0

```
SELECT a1.Attend_Date, t.P
FROM Student s1, Attendance a1

RIGHT JOIN (
SELECT a2.Attend_Date, COUNT(a2.AttendDet_Type) as P
FROM Student s2, Attendance a2
WHERE s2.Stud_ID = a2.Stud_ID 
AND s2.Stud_Class = '1A1' 
AND a2.Attend_Date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-01'  
AND a2.AttendDet_Type = 'P'
GROUP BY a2.Attend_Date
) as t ON a1.Attend_Date = t.Attend_Date

WHERE s1.Stud_ID = a1.Stud_ID
AND s1.Stud_Class = '1A1' 
AND a1.Attend_Date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-01'  
GROUP BY a1.Attend_Date
```